# Valgrind (Helgrind): possible data race debugging

Tags: c, multithreading, valgrind, race-condition

Can someone help me to clearify if this is really caused by a mistake of mine or because helgrind can not trace it correctly in this case?

I am also wondering what the 'at ...' means. In this case it is
`at 0x48488A6: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)`. Does it mean that the condition is found there and since this is not a function I wrote, it's not my fault?

I could fix any race condition error but this one.

EDIT START:

I have the full code in [this repo](https://github.com/mortytheshorty/thread) if this helps:
Just build and test with:

```
git clone https://github.com/mortytheshorty/thread && cd thread
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
valgrind -tool=helgrind -s ./simple_thread_test
```

The test function:

```
void *thread_test(void *arg)
{
    struct timespec timespec = { 0 };
    timespec.tv_nsec = CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 500;
    char *p = arg;
    while(*p++) {
        printf("%s\n", (char *) arg);
        nanosleep(&timespec, NULL);
    }
}
```

EDIT_END

The header:

```
// (c) 2023 Florian Giest
// This code is licensed under MIT license (see LICENSE.txt for details)

#ifndef _DEBUG_H// BEGIN INCLUDE GUARD
#define _DEBUG_H

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                              DEPENDANICIES                                            */
/*********************************************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                               DEFINITIONS                                             */
/*********************************************************************************************************/

/* if DEBUG is defines it enables the macro for logging the steps 
   of every function which calls these functions/macros */
#ifdef DEBUG
 /* pretty simple debug function expaned by macro 'debug()'
    write DEBUG: at the first place followed by the calling pthread id
    and a formatstring and its arguments
 */
 void xdebug(pthread_t threadid, const char *function, const char *fmt, ...);
 #define debug(fmt, ...) xdebug(pthread_self(), __func__, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
 /* same as for 'xdebug()' but for error and also prints errno string if
    errno is set.
 */
 void xdebug_error(pthread_t threadid, const char *function, const char *fmt, ...);
 #define debug_error(fmt, ...) xdebug_error(pthread_self(), __func__, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
 #define debug_error(x, ...)
 #define debug(x, ...)
#endif


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                           FUNCTION DEFINITIONS                                        */
/*********************************************************************************************************/

#endif
```

The code:

```
// (c) 2023 Florian Giest
// This code is licensed under MIT license (see LICENSE.txt for details)

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                              DEPENDANICIES                                            */
/*********************************************************************************************************/

#include <pthread.h>

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                               DEFINITIONS                                             */
/*********************************************************************************************************/

pthread_mutex_t debugmtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                           FUNCTION DEFINITIONS                                        */
/*********************************************************************************************************/

void xdebug(pthread_t threadid, const char *function, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&debugmtx);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    fprintf(stdout, "DEBUG: thread[%ld] %s(): ", threadid, function);
    vfprintf(stdout, fmt, args);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    va_end(args);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&debugmtx);
}


void xdebug_error(pthread_t threadid, const char *function, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&debugmtx);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: thread[%ld] %s(): ", threadid, function);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    if(errno) {
        fprintf(stderr, " (%s)", strerror(errno));
    }
    fputc('\n', stderr);

    va_end(args);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&debugmtx);
}
```

Valgrind(Helgrind) output:

```
==30008==
==30008== 6 errors in context 1 of 2:
==30008== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==30008==
==30008==  Lock at 0x4856200 was first observed
==30008==    at 0x483FEDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4853939: xdebug (error.c:34)
==30008==    by 0x48530FC: thread_create (thread.c:156)
==30008==    by 0x109326: main (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==  Address 0x4856200 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "debugmtx"
==30008==
==30008== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x4A79045 by thread #2
==30008== Locks held: none
==30008==    at 0x48488A6: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4914631: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1236)
==30008==    by 0x4914631: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==30008==    by 0x49094F7: puts (ioputs.c:40)
==30008==    by 0x1092B5: thread_test (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==    by 0x48530A8: thread_worker (thread.c:126)
==30008==    by 0x4842B1A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x486A608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==30008==    by 0x49A4132: clone (clone.S:95)
==30008==
==30008== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #1
==30008== Locks held: 1, at address 0x4856200
==30008==    at 0x48488A6: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4914631: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1236)
==30008==    by 0x4914631: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==30008==    by 0x48FB971: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==30008==    by 0x48E6C69: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
==30008==    by 0x4853992: xdebug (error.c:38)
==30008==    by 0x48529C6: jobqueue_push (jobqueue.c:114)
==30008==    by 0x4853517: thread_addjob (thread.c:264)
==30008==    by 0x109403: main (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==  Address 0x4a79045 is 5 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 alloc'd
==30008==    at 0x483C893: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4906D03: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==30008==    by 0x4916ECF: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==30008==    by 0x4915F2F: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==30008==    by 0x49146B4: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==30008==    by 0x49146B4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==30008==    by 0x48FB971: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==30008==    by 0x48E6C69: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
==30008==    by 0x4853992: xdebug (error.c:38)
==30008==    by 0x48530FC: thread_create (thread.c:156)
==30008==    by 0x109326: main (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==30008==
==30008==
==30008== 7 errors in context 2 of 2:
==30008== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==30008==
==30008==  Lock at 0x4856200 was first observed
==30008==    at 0x483FEDF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4853939: xdebug (error.c:34)
==30008==    by 0x48530FC: thread_create (thread.c:156)
==30008==    by 0x109326: main (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==  Address 0x4856200 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "debugmtx"
==30008==
==30008== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x4A79046 by thread #1
==30008== Locks held: 1, at address 0x4856200
==30008==    at 0x48488A6: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4914631: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1236)
==30008==    by 0x4914631: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==30008==    by 0x48FB971: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==30008==    by 0x48E6C69: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
==30008==    by 0x4853992: xdebug (error.c:38)
==30008==    by 0x485357F: thread_pause (thread.c:275)
==30008==    by 0x10939A: main (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==
==30008== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==30008== Locks held: none
==30008==    at 0x4915DC8: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:781)
==30008==    by 0x4909599: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==30008==    by 0x1092B5: thread_test (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==    by 0x48530A8: thread_worker (thread.c:126)
==30008==    by 0x4842B1A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x486A608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==30008==    by 0x49A4132: clone (clone.S:95)
==30008==  Address 0x4a79046 is 6 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 alloc'd
==30008==    at 0x483C893: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==30008==    by 0x4906D03: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==30008==    by 0x4916ECF: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==30008==    by 0x4915F2F: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==30008==    by 0x49146B4: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==30008==    by 0x49146B4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==30008==    by 0x48FB971: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==30008==    by 0x48E6C69: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
==30008==    by 0x4853992: xdebug (error.c:38)
==30008==    by 0x48530FC: thread_create (thread.c:156)
==30008==    by 0x109326: main (in /home/flo/projects/thread/build/simple_thread_test)
==30008==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
==30008==
--30008--
--30008-- used_suppression:    238 helgrind-glibc2X-005 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/default.supp:963
--30008-- used_suppression:     36 helgrind-glibc2X-004 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/default.supp:949
==30008==
==30008== ERROR SUMMARY: 13 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 274 from 95)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helgrind intercepts functions like `memcpy` and uses its own version in vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so.

That has nothing to do with the problem.

It looks to me like you have another function `thread_test` that is also doing some I/O. You didn't post the source for that function. Helgrind says you don't have any locks for that.

Try using the same lock for whatever I/O you are calling from `thread_test`.

Comment: I edited the post and added the function. It is quite simple that I don't understand what it has to do with the error. Maybe have a look at the repo, would appreciate it.

Comment: I'll give it a go the next time I boot Linux.

Comment: The code is quite noisy with warnings. What is this Python stuff going in C `_thread_destroy`? That's UB.I don't get any warnings with the latest Valgrind. There is a suppression for glibc-io-xsputn-mempcpy.

Comment: 1. What you mean with noisy with warnings if you don't get any with the latest valgrind? 2. Yeah me either, I wasn't sure how and where I will use it but since I am sure now I renamed it to `thread_selfdestroy()`. What version do you use? Ubuntu package or compiled from source? I go with `valgrind-3.15.0` from the latest stabel ubuntu repo.

Comment: Your source code compiling is noisy - extra semicolons, unused static vartiabled There are no errors with Helgrind on FreeBSD 13.1 or Fedora 37. I generally use Valgrind built from git. 3.15 is a bit old - released 3 years ago. 3.21 was released just over a week ago.

Comment: However the suppression that should cover the errors that you are seeing was added to Valgrind in 2015 (3.14) so you should have it. Can you build Valgrind from source? Othgerwise can you find "default.supp" in your Valgrind install dir and check that it has a suppression called helgrind-glibc-io-xsputn-mempcpy ?

Comment: Noisy compilation fixed. Build Valgrind from source, no errors as you said. Thanks for your work on Valgrind btw.